# How to customize the built-in chooser(dialogue box) of share intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to customize the `createChooser` of share intent in `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share via"));`?
Showing the apps not in a dialogue box maybe in scroll view as buttons

[image: Built in chooser]

[image: custom chooser]

Answer (score 1):

**String urlToShare = "www.google.com"**

`code to share link twitter`

```
try {
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getParent())
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setText("Sharing text with image link \n "+urlToShare).setStream(null)
                .getIntent()
                .setPackage("com.twitter.android");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If we failed (not native FB app installed), try share through SEND
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String sharerUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + urlToShare;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

`code to share link google plus`

```
try {
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getParent())
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setText("Sharing text with image link \n "+urlToShare).setStream(null)
                .getIntent()
                .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If we failed (not native FB app installed), try share through SEND
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String sharerUrl = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=" + urlToShare;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

`code to share link whatsapp`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by getting the share options as activities and pass them to your adapter, i am posting a sample code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
List activities = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
```

By this you will get share Intents in activities object and then you can convert it to Object Array some thing like this

```
Objects[] item = activities.toArray();

for( int i=0; i<item.length; i++ ) {

    ResolveInfo infoName = (ResolveInfo) items[i];
    String name =  info.activityInfo.name;
    Drawable logo = info.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());

    // Set them to your Views
}
```

and when your view is clicked and you want to perform the share functionality you will do some thing like this

```
ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) item(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your Text");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Objects[] item = activities.toArray(); showing incompatible type error...I tried   Objects[] item = activities.toArray(new Objects[activities.size()]); ..also showing same error

Comment: will you please share the logcat

Comment: the code is not building.... in this line Objects[] items = activities.toArray(); it is showing incompatible type: required Java.util.Objects[] found Java.lang.Objects[] ..screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9b83c8qih7jyka/Untitled1.zip?dl=0

Comment: Objects[] items = (Objects[]) activities.toArray();

Comment: thanks brother...can you help me out for this error 'inconvartible types;cannot cast java.util.objects to android content.pm.resolveinfo' in line  String name = (ResolveInfo) items[i]).activityInfo.applicationInfo
                    .loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();

Comment: String name = ((ResolveInfo) items[i]).activityInfo.applicationInfo .loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();

Comment: Still showing an error String name = ((ResolveInfo) items[i]).activityInfo.applicationInfo .loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();  https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9b83c8qih7jyka/Untitled1.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have done to share link and image to another apps something like this just try

```
 /*
 * Method to share either text or URL.
 */
private void shareTextUrl() {
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
    // what to do with it.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.com");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share link!"));
}

/*
 * Method to share any image.
 */
private void shareImage() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
    // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setType("image/*");

    // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
    // directory
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/myImage.png";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
}
```

Comment: I am familiar with the process ...when you share,a dialogue box will appear ...but my question was I don't want the dialogue box..I want to show the apps in a scroll view as buttons..after clicking an app icon sharing action will be done for that app

Comment: do you have any sample code?or can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @TauseefMamun i paste my code below. Did want to share image little bit changes was need. now i just share only text or link